# Performance of any()

Tags: python

This is mostly an exercise in learning Python. I wrote this function to test if a number is prime:

```
def p1(n):
    for d in xrange(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % d == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Then I realized I can make easily rewrite it using any():

```
def p2(n):
    return not any((n % d == 0) for d in xrange(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1))
```

Performance-wise, I was expecting p2 to be faster than, or at the very least as fast as, p1 because any() is builtin, but for a large-ish prime, p2 is quite a bit slower:

```
$ python -m timeit -n 100000 -s "import test" "test.p1(999983)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 60.2 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 100000 -s "import test" "test.p2(999983)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 88.1 usec per loop
```

Am I using any() incorrectly here? Is there a way to write this function using any() so that it's as far as iterating myself?

Update: Numbers for an even larger prime

```
$  python -m timeit -n 1000 -s "import test" "test.p1(9999999999971)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 181 msec per loop

$  python -m timeit -n 1000 -s "import test" "test.p2(9999999999971)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 261 msec per loop
```

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any it does look quite like what you wrote.

Comment: @rightføld A 50% increase is a small difference?

Comment: No, but <1000 iterations is a small enough number that a couple extra stack frames (not to mention the stuff happening elsewhere in your computer at the time) are still significant compared to the body of the loop.

Comment: Not really anything to do with your question, but out of curiosity (and my poor math skills) would you mind explaining to me why you only need to use the range `xrange(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1)`? I've always done it as `xrange(2, n)`.

Comment: @IanAuld, if any `x` above `sqrt(n)` would divide `n`, then the other factor would be `< sqrt(n)` and you would have found it by then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance difference is minimal, but the reason it exists is that `any` incurs building a generator expression, and an extra function call, compared to the for loop. Both have identical behaviors, though (shortcut evaluation).

As the size of your input grows, the difference won't diminish (I was wrong) because you're using a generator expression, and iterating over it requires calling a method (`.next()`) on it and an extra stack frame. `any` does that under the hood, of course.

The for loop is iterating over an `xrange` object. `any` is iterating over a generator expression, which itself is iterating over an `xrange` object.

Either way, use whichever produces the most readable/maintainable code. Choosing one over the other will have little, if any, performance impact on whatever program you're writing.

Comment: Thanks. I understand they have identical behaviors, just trying to learn the right usage of the builtin functions since I'm new to Python. But I'm not seeing the difference diminish for even larger primes (I'll update the question in a bit). Even for a 13-digit prime, the difference is still around 50% (~180ms vs ~270ms). I get your point about readability, but for this particular exercise, I'm more interested in understanding the usage of any().

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I disagree about it not having any performance impact. One implementation seems to be consistently 50% slower than the other, so depending on how often this function is called, there could be a significant perf difference. That said, your point about the generator expression makes complete sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: Well, as usual, write working, readable code, *then* profile and optimize. Always in that order ;)